# Why Mobile hotspot data speed differ from app to app?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, youtube, wifi-configuration, hotspot

Currently I am working from Home in my village in India and using Airtel as my main mobile network to have internet connection. My phone is `Xiaomi Red mi note 8 pro`. First SIM slot is having Airtel and second is having Vodafone.

My every setting is up to date. My PC is having `CentOS 7` and I am using `D LINK DWA 125` adapter to have internet from mobile device. When i start using my internet my speed is never constant. If i am using YouTube, My net speed is excellent but other than that not a single app is working properly.

YouTube is showing me the speed between 500KBPS - 1.5MBPS. But as soon as I minimize the youtube and open any other app, Speed drops from 500-800KBps to 5-6 KBps.

I am able to connect to remote but after connection, it keeps on breaking the connection.

*NOTE: Airtel is having 4G connection and i can see the full bar.*

Let me know if any other information you guys need from my side. Happy to provide but please resolve it.

#update: I have started my laptop and started torrent and speed is showing more than 2MBps at the moment. SO, I turn off the torrent and speed dropped from 2-3MBps to 10-20KBps.

Comment: Your ISP may well be prioritising YouTube traffic.

Comment: How to know that and how to resolve that?